# Bootstrap table missing some icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[Toolbars for 2 different tables on same page. Code is the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxpSr.png)When using multiple bootstrap tables on a single page, the pagination hide/show icon is not showing on some of the tables. Using the inspector, it shows that the ones that are not working are adding the glypicon class while the ones that do work are adding the fa class.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table1" data-height="355" data-toggle="table" data-show-refresh="false"
                                   data-show-export="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true"
                                   data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"
                                   data-minimum-count-columns="2" data-show-pagination-switch="true"
                                   data-pagination="true" data-page-size="[20]" data-page-list="[10,20,25,50,100,250,500,All]"
                                   data-toolbar="#toolbar1"
                                   data-show-footer="false"  data-side-pagination="client" data-icons-prefix="fa"
```

Comment: This will get closed if you don't show some code. However if you are using Bootstrap 4, glyphicons are no longer part of bootstrap. That is BS3. If you want an icon set, you have to import one, like font awesome.

Comment: We can't help when we don't know how those classes are getting added to the HTML. Are they added manually, or through code? If it is through code, then please show us that code so we can see why it might be going wrong.